# How can I specify a [DllImport] path at runtime (embedded inside .msi file)

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, dllimport, custom-action

I want to import a dll into my C# project to call it's functions using DllImport.
I have my dll that needs to be imported as part of my .msi file.

It does work when I specify the full path to the DLL, but that is outside .msi file.

---

I am facing the dllNotFoundException problem.

```
<Binary Id="CustomAction2.CA.dll"
src="../artifacts/CustomAction2.CA.dll" />

<CustomAction Id="Install"                
        Execute="deferred"
        BinaryKey="CustomAction2.CA.dll" 
        DllEntry="CustomAction1" />

<CustomAction Id="InstallWithProperty"
        Property="Install"
        Value="location=[DEFAULT_INSTALLDIR]$FULL_NAME;name=myDll.dll" 
        Execute="immediate"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>      
  <Custom Action="InstallWithProperty" After="InstallFiles"/>
  <Custom Action="Install" After="InstallWithProperty" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

when Custom action is invoked it says
I get below exception

`Exception thrown by custom action: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'myDll.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) at CustomAction2.CustomActions.ConfigDriver(IntPtr hwndParent, UInt16 fRequest, String lpszDriver, String lpszArgs, String lpszMsg, UInt16 cbMsgMax, Int64& pcbMsgOut) at CustomAction2.CustomActions.CustomAction1(Session session) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture) at Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.CustomActionProxy.InvokeCustomAction(Int32 sessionHandle, String entryPoint, IntPtr remotingDelegatePtr) CustomAction Install returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)`

Can somebody help. I want to use myDll.dll for further installation, which is part of .msi file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have MSI file which has .DLL inside it and you want to pInvoke it?

Whatever you're doing this for, it sounds bad. You might rehink your approach,
however, for an actual answer:

To get you started, here is a little bit of C# code:

```
String inputFile = @"C:\\Install1.msi";
            // Get the type of the Windows Installer object 
            Type installerType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer");

            // Create the Windows Installer object 
            WindowsInstaller.Installer installer = (WindowsInstaller.Installer)Activator.CreateInstance(installerType);

            // Open the MSI database in the input file 
            Database database = installer.OpenDatabase(inputFile, MsiOpenDatabaseMode.msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly);

            // Open a view on the Property table for the version property 
            View view = database.OpenView("SELECT * FROM Property WHERE Property = 'ProductVersion'");

            // Execute the view query 
            view.Execute(null);

            // Get the record from the view 
            Record record = view.Fetch();

            // Get the version from the data 
            string version = record.get_StringData(2);
```

Now mind you, it does not extract file from the MSI, but it's good start. In order to actually extract from MSI, you need to change the code a little.

Here is VB code that does it, note the SQL-syntax like query.

```
 Function ExtractIcon(IconName, OutputFile) 

                Const msiReadStreamAnsi = 2 



                Dim oDatabase 

                Set oDatabase = Session.Database 



                Dim View 

                Set View = oDatabase.OpenView("SELECT * FROM Icon WHERE 
Name = '" &amp; IconName &amp; "'") 

                View.Execute 



                Dim Record 

                Set Record = View.Fetch 

                Dim BinaryData 



                BinaryData = Record.ReadStream(2, Record.DataSize(2), 
msiReadStreamAnsi) 



                Dim FSO 

                Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

                Dim Stream 

                Set Stream = FSO.CreateTextFile(OutputFile, True) 

                Stream.Write BinaryData 

                Stream.Close 

                Set FSO = Nothing 

            End Function
```

You need to convert it into C#, it's going to be easy task. 
After that, you need to actually use dynamic pInvoke. Ps you can also use normal pInvoke if you extract the DLL into your projects folder, and use relative paths.

To use dynamic pInvoke:

follow this article; http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2007/01/06/typesafe-getprocaddress.aspx

It's little neat code:

```
 using(UnmanagedLibrary lib = new UnmanagedLibrary("kernel32")  // becomes call to LoadLibrary
   { 
      Action<String> function = lib.GetUnmanagedFunction<Action<String>>("DeleteFile"); // GetProcAddress
      function(@"c:\tmp.txt");
   } // implict call to lib.Dispose, which calls FreeLibrary.
```

If you feel like a god, you can load the DLL into memory never extracting it anywhere. This is useful if you have amazing DLL that should be always hidden from anyone. It's just for information - it's pretty hard ^_^

Comment: <Binary Id="CustomAction2.CA.dll"
src="../artifacts/CustomAction2.CA.dll" />
<CustomAction Id="Install"                
        Execute="deferred"
        BinaryKey="CustomAction2.CA.dll" 
        DllEntry="CustomAction1" />
<CustomAction Id="InstallWithProperty"
        Property="Install"
        Value="location=[DEFAULT_INSTALLDIR]$FULL_NAME;name=myDll.dll"       Execute="immediate"/>        
<InstallExecuteSequence>      
  <Custom Action="InstallWithProperty" After="InstallFiles"/>
  <Custom Action="Install" After="InstallWithProperty" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>